# Rails nested routes with controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, routes

I have these routes:

```
      namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do


      namespace :v1 do
      resources :cars

      resources :users, only: [:create] do
        member do
          resources :cars, controller: "user/cars"
          resources :friends, controller: "user/friends"
          resources :drink, controller: "user/drinks"
        end
      end

    end
  end
```

Is there a way to abstract the non-dry controller definition on those nested resources?

EDIT:

my ideal example output is:

namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    namespace :v1 do

```
  resources :cars

  resources :users, only: [:create] do
    member do
      resources :cars
      resources :friends
      resources :drink
    end
  end

end
```

end

and that the three nested resources use that controller previously stated

Comment: Not quite sure what you mean - can you give an example of how you would like the output to look?

Answer (score 0):

finally after research I came up with this:

```
  namespace :api, defaults: {format: :json} do
    namespace :v1 do
      resources :users, only: [:create]
      resources :cars
      scope "users/:id", as: "users", module: "users" do
         resources :cars
         resources :friends
         resources :drink
      end
    end
  end
```